# A tree on n vertices where every vertex has degree 1 or 4. Prove that n ≡ 2 (mod 3)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let T be a tree tree on n vertices where every vertex has degree 1 or 4. Prove that n ≡ 2 (mod 3)

Comment: Start with a base case: the $K_{1,4}$ graph.  Continue by induction by taking a vertex of degree 1 and forcing it to be degree 4 by adding three additional vertices of degree one adjacent to it.  At each step, $n$ is increased by 3 proving the claim by induction.  Note, this is true for trees, but not for forests.

Comment: @JMoravitz: You’ve missed $K_2$.

Comment: Good point, include that as a base case as well then.  Intuitively, every tree with this property is constructable from one of those starting points by the process described above.  A few extra words about that will complete the proof.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the degrees of all vertices is congruent to $n$ mod $3$ (since it is a sum of $n$ terms that are all congruent to $1$ mod 3) and is also equal to $2n-2$ since the tree has $n-1$ edges. Thus
$$2n-2\equiv n\pmod{3}$$
so
$$n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If every vertex has degree $1$, the tree is $K_2$. Otherwise, pick a vertex $v$ of degree $4$, and split it into $4$ vertices, one adjacent to each edge of the original tree that was adjacent to $v$. You now have a forest of four trees, each of which is smaller than the original tree, and each of which has only vertices of degrees $1$ and $4$. Now apply the natural induction hypothesis.